# join with union not working in mysql

Tags: mysql

i am using the following union query with left join query

```
    (SELECT id as hotspots_id,location as town,gmlat,gmlng,street,country,zipcode as 

plz,name,description ,c.id as cat_id ,c.* FROM `jos_skopelos_pages_list` LEFT JOIN 

    `jos_skopelos_listcategories` AS c ON jos_skopelos_pages_list.type=cat_id WHERE 

published = 1) UNION ALL (SELECT id as hotspots_id,location as 

town,gmlat,gmlng,street,country,zipcode as plz,name,description ,c.id as cat_id ,c.* FROM 

`jos_skopelos_accomodation` LEFT JOIN `jos_skopelos_listcategories` AS c ON 

 jos_skopelos_accomodation.type=cat_id WHERE published = 1) UNION ALL (SELECT id as 

 hotspots_id,location as town,gmlat,gmlng,street,country,zipcode as plz,name,description 
,c.id as cat_id ,c.* FROM `jos_skopelos_entertainment` LEFT JOIN 

`jos_skopelos_listcategories` AS c ON jos_skopelos_entertainment.type=cat_id WHERE 

published = 1) UNION ALL (SELECT id as hotspots_id,location as 

  town,gmlat,gmlng,street,country,zipcode as plz,name,description ,c.id as cat_id ,c.* 

FROM `jos_skopelos_realstate` LEFT JOIN `jos_skopelos_listcategories` AS c ON 

 jos_skopelos_realstate.type=cat_id WHERE published = 1)
```

Above query is working file with union statement but when i add the left join statement it is giving the error of "#1052 - Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous".Please keep in mind when i remove left join means the table "jos_skopelos_listcategories" my query work fine but when i add left join statement it gives the above error please help

Comment: Each time I see a query that is formatted that way, I am sure that the person who posted it, has not made any effort to understand what it does and why it does it that way.

Comment: my database is not much normalized so i have to write such query but i will learn from that mistake  n will take care next tym ut right now i need a solution for this

Comment: @user972809 - the formatting of a query has nothing to do with normalization of your database. FWIW, you should alias your other tables and use that alias in your column lists. It will solve your error (you are already doing it for `c.id as cat_id` but not for all your other columns).

Comment: Yea I was in the middle of reformatting your code but it was taking so long because there's alot of it and it's all crammed together that I decided just to stop.

Comment: @user97289, the problem is that to understand why your query does not work, one should format it in a way to understand what it does, since rare people can understand queries from a byte stream. It would be better if you would be the person who would organize the query in an understandable manner. Then probably you will find the error yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think for all of them you need to define the columns more clearly, especially since id is located in both of the tables you are joining together. For example change in the first line, id to jos_skopelos_pages_list.id. On the last section change id to jos_skopelos_realstate.id and for all the unions in between. Also when you say `LEFT JOIN jos_skopelos_listcategories AS c`, you can just write `LEFT JOIN jos_skopelos_listcategories c`